# Why aren't Chainlink Keeper transactions showing up on Polyscan (Matic Mumbai)?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, chainlink, etherscan

I have a chainlink keeper performing upkeep on the `0x13136d7f46bb8e5514050D6e43109ea67D7b9e3E` on Matic Mumbai. The deployed contract is the example code provided on chainlink keeper documentation. I can observe the state change on every upkeep on Remix. The Keeper dashboard shows the transactions too. I even added an event to the performUpkeep function and I can read the events too via Openzepplin Defender. But on polyscan, I'm not able to see any transactions. Even Defender can't see any transaction. The transaction hash mentioned on the defender dashboard shows the transaction from keeper to Keeper Registry Contract ([example](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x03ddf4b33af13399d3cd4f14e088b97d3c20345bdd9f97db9d46965865ca6641)).

Why is this happening? How can I look at the transactions to my contract?

[image: Keeper Transactions showing on https://keepers.chain.link/mumbai/83]

Comment: have you check the internal txt?

Comment: Yes, there aren't any. Not even the tab. You can check [here](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x13136d7f46bb8e5514050D6e43109ea67D7b9e3E). The Events I added inside performUpkeep is emited and shows on polyscan, but transactions aren't.

Comment: I'd test wtih kovan. Mumbai often has weird issues....